# define endpoint in WSO2 Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

i have a flow which execute 3 stored procedures from Postgress and her flow is the next:
[image]

and the flow code api definition is the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/animalstore" name="AnimalStoreFlowServices" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <!-- Lógica para llamar al procedimiento almacenado -->
            <log description="Log Request Payload" level="full"/>
            <switch description="Route based on the Operation" source="json-eval($.Operation)">
                <case regex="datosCliente">
                    <dblookup>
                        <connection>
                            <pool>
                                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/animalstore</url>
                                <user>postgres</user>
                                <password>passwd12</password>
                            </pool>
                        </connection>
                        <statement>
                            <sql><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM get_animals_data();]]></sql>
                            <result column="nombrecompleto" name="variable1"/>
                            <result column="cuenta_id" name="variable3"/>
                            <result column="domicilio" name="variable2"/>
                        </statement>
                        <!-- Set database connection -->
                    </dblookup>
                    <!-- Mapping the captured values in a property list-->
                    <property description="Set response properties" expression="$ctx:variable1" name="VariableList1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property description="Set response properties" expression="$ctx:variable2" name="VariableList2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property description="Set response properties" expression="$ctx:variable3" name="VariableList3" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <!-- Configure the response with the captured values -->
                    <payloadFactory description="Create response payload" media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <Response xmlns="">
                                <datosCliente>
                                    <Nombre>$1</Nombre>
                                    <Domicilio>$2</Domicilio>
                                    <NúmeroCliente>$3</NúmeroCliente>
                                </datosCliente>
                            </Response>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:VariableList1"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:VariableList2"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:VariableList3"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                </case>
                <case regex="datosCuenta">
                    <dblookup>
                        <connection>
                            <pool>
                                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/animalstore</url>
                                <user>postgres</user>
                                <password>passwd12</password>
                            </pool>
                        </connection>
                        <statement>
                            <sql><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM get_herfamily_data();]]></sql>
                            <result column="numerocuenta" name="variable1"/>
                            <result column="nombrebanco" name="variable3"/>
                            <result column="vigencia" name="variable2"/>
                        </statement>
                        <!-- Set database connection -->
                    </dblookup>
                    <!-- Mapping the captured values in a property list-->
                    <property description="Set response properties" expression="$ctx:variable1" name="VariableList1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property description="Set response properties" expression="$ctx:variable2" name="VariableList2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property description="Set response properties" expression="$ctx:variable3" name="VariableList3" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <!-- Configure the response with the captured values -->
                    <payloadFactory description="Create response payload" media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <Response xmlns="">
                                <datosCuenta>
                                    <numeroCuenta>$1</numeroCuenta>
                                    <vigencia>$2</vigencia>
                                    <banco>$3</banco>
                                </datosCuenta>
                            </Response>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:VariableList1"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:VariableList2"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:VariableList3"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                </case>
                <case regex="datosSaldo">
                    <dblookup>
                        <connection>
                            <pool>
                                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/animalstore</url>
                                <user>postgres</user>
                                <password>passwd12</password>
                            </pool>
                        </connection>
                        <statement>
                            <sql><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM get_clinic_profile();]]></sql>
                            <result column="saldo" name="variable1"/>
                            <result column="fecha" name="variable2"/>
                        </statement>
                        <!-- Set database connection -->
                    </dblookup>
                    <!-- Mapping the captured values in a property list-->
                    <property description="Set response properties" expression="$ctx:variable1" name="VariableList1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property description="Set response properties" expression="$ctx:variable2" name="VariableList2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <!-- Configure the response with the captured values -->
                    <payloadFactory description="Create response payload" media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <Response xmlns="">
                                <datosSaldo>
                                    <saldo>$1</saldo>
                                    <fecha>$2</fecha>
                                </datosSaldo>
                            </Response>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:VariableList1"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:VariableList2"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <payloadFactory description="Create response payload for unsupported operation" media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <Message xmlns="">Unsupported operation.</Message>
                        </format>
                        <args/>
                    </payloadFactory>
                </default>
            </switch>
            <property description="Set message type" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <respond description="Send result to the client"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

at this point i use POSTMAN for get the stored procedure values and i can do it corrrectly

But i have understand that for do a unit tests i should have an end-point define for each stored procedure, anyone can orient me about how define an EndPoint?
which one should i use?
an endpoint from the Pallette or a Defined Endpoint? i need two kicks for understand completely how do a wso2 flow service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create an Endpoint for the stored procedure execution in your case, Endpoints are used to do HTTP calls. Since you are using the DBLookup mediator you can't do a HTTP call on it. So you can write a unit test to test the entire API. If you really want to do an HTTP call to execute the stored procedure you can create a [Dataservice](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/creating-artifacts/data-services/creating-data-services/) instead of using the DbLookup mediator and then use the Call Mediator to call it.

Comment: ok thanks, I understand complete, in fact I  made this procedure stored first in a data service 4 days ago.